# what symplectic manifolds that show up in real applications are not a cotangent bundle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I'm reading a bit more about symplectic geometry and going through Ralph Abraham's *Foundations of Mechanics*.
One of the points that's emphasized early on is that Hamiltonian mechanics is naturally posed on a symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$, where $\omega$ is a non-degenerate 2-form on $M$ such that $d\omega = 0$.
A rich source of symplectic manifolds comes from taking the cotangent bundle $T^*Q$ of some underlying configuration manifold $Q$.
The cotangent bundle can be given a canonical symplectic structure by taking the exterior derivative of the 1-form $\theta$ that looks like $p\cdot dq$ in local coordinates.
Indeed, pretty much every mechanical system that I can think of is the cotangent bundle of some configuration space:

- for the gravitational $n$-body problem, the configuration manifold is $(\mathbb{R}^3)^n - \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is the set of all points where two or more of the coordinates are equal: $\Delta = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) : x_i = x_j\text{ for some }i, j\}$.
- for a rotating top, the configuration manifold is SO(3)
- for a mechanical system with holonomic constraints, the configuration manifold is the zero-contour of some smooth function $g$, i.e. $Q = \{q \in \mathbb{R}^n: g(q) = 0\}$.

**What are examples in mechanics where the phase space is not a cotangent bundle?**
Do these more general symplectic manifolds show up in problems with nonholonomic constraints like a rolling ball?

Answer (score 1):

Some examples of symplectic manifolds that are not cotangent bundles are the 2-torus and the sphere. In general, you can always endow a 2d manifold with a symplectic structure, as long as it is orientable. Indeed, orientable manifolds have well-defined volume forms, which since you are on 2-dimensional manifolds are even symplectic forms (being non-degenerate and naturally closed).

Comment: Sure I'm aware that $S^{2n}$ or $T^{2n}$ can be given symplectic structures, what I want to know is what mechanical systems have these manifold as phase space?

Comment: If you have any Poisson system, like free rigid-body or Lotka-volterra, and the poisson structure is degenerate, the dynamics has symplectic invariant manifolds given by the joint level sets of the casimirs. The system then becomes Hamiltonian on them, and they are not cotangent bundles in general. For example, for the rigid body, you get spheres as invariant manifolds

Comment: The process of symplectic reduction (given a symmetry of your system) should reduce your phase space to a quotient space which doesn't necessarily have to be a cotangent bundle (for example over a smaller configuration space) on it's own.